# In Commerce 2, how can I load an order item's 'purchased entity' object given its ID?

Tags: commerce

I have need to load an order item's 'purchased entity' object so that I can object the base product's title for an order item.

In my scope, I have the order_item object and, from there I have access to the 'purchased entity' **ID** number. But I can figure out how to load the 'purchased entity'object from this ID number.

EDIT:

Thanks to Chance G I was able to achieve what I needed by:

```
  $product_variation = $order_item->getPurchasedEntity();
  $product_id = $product_variation->product_id->getString();
  $product = \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product::load($product_id);
  $product_title = $product->getTitle();
```

Comment: I didn't realize you need the product title and not the product variation title. I can confirm this later but if you don't need the intermediate variables you can probably do: `$order_item->getPurchasedEntity()->getProduct()->getTitle();`

Comment: Nice! That snipped did indeed work. Nice and clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your $order_item is an instance of the OrderItem class you should be able to do:

```
$product_variation = $order_item->getPurchasedEntity();
$title = $product_variation->getTitle();
```

If you have an $order you should be able to do:

```
foreach ($order->getItems() as $order_item) {
  $product_variation = $order_item->getPurchasedEntity();
  $title = $product_variation->getTitle();
}
```

Comment: I have a custom field in variation, How I can get the value? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/282933/print-custom-product-variation-field-in-order-email-confirmation/282934